# Need to add where clause to a table adapter

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, dataset, tableadapter

I have a dataset setup by using the Visual Studio wizard and in the form is this line of code:

```
Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentsDataSet.Students)
```

The select statement for the table adapter is:

```
SELECT ID, Forename, Surname, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, PostCode, 
       PrimaryPhone, SecondaryPhone, DateOfBirth, email, Grade, GPA, ParentID 
  FROM Students
```

Can you tell me how to add a Where clause using coding on this table adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an SQLCommand object, something like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID=@ID", myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 5)
Me.StudentsTableAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentsDataSet.Students)
```

Comment: I tried the code but I get an error on .SelectCommand stating 'SelectCommand' is not a member of StudentsTableAdapter. How do I make it a member of the table adapter?

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen Then what is your `StudentsTableAdapter`?  `SelectCommand` is a get or set property of the SqlDataAdapter object.  Your error is telling me it's not.

Comment: I didn't create the the table adapter by hand. Instead it was created for me when I dragged a column from the data source onto the form. I just deleted the binding navigator and bound the controls from the properties window and built my coding around that.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code from a university project.

```
query = SELECT icode, category, iname, weight, price, pic, qty FROM   dbo.item_entry where(iname=@iname)
```

code:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.item_entryTableAdapter.FillByItem(this.jewllary_DatabaseDataSet.item_entry, comboBox2.Text);
}
```